# Asp.Net MVC Embedded Second Application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, routes

I'm gettin an error when embedding a second Asp.net application into the website. The application is packaged via web deploy into a zip file and imported onto IIS via web deploy.

Best regards,
Robert

[image: ***enter image description here***]

Comment: The path looks a bit wierd. Is that path "\\.\aux\...." can be accessed from your file explorer?Besides, when you deploy to IIS, you need to replace the application pool with a domain account that have enough permission to access the share folder path. So please ensure the application can be accessed from VS and the path is correct. Then use an valid domain account as app pool idenitty.

Comment: @JokiesDing it's not a file, it's generated by the framework

Comment: Are you hosting the application in a virtual application and using an application pool identity with enough permission?